# What is the notation to logical OR a series?

Tags: notation

I am looking for something similar to Sigma summation notation, but for logical or.  If I have a series of function results that I would like to OR together, how do I denote that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe make $\lor$ or $\land$ bigger using wedge and vee like this

`\bigvee\limits_{i=1}^n x_i` $\bigvee\limits_{i=1}^n x_i$

`\bigwedge\limits_{i=1}^n x_i` $\bigwedge\limits_{i=1}^n x_i$

Could also use `\bigoplus` $\bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^n x_i$ for xor.

Note that if the symbol exists in small but not in big shape, you can build your own nevertheless using this construction:

- § will give `\operatorname*{\Large{§}}\limits_{i=1}^n` $\operatorname*{\Large{§}}\limits_{i=1}^n x_i$